# Ubuntu "find" command for count of files in each directory unexpected count

Tags: file, ubuntu, count, find

I am using the `find` command to give me a list of the number of files in each directory and sub-directory.  This is the command

```
find . -maxdepth 100 -mindepth 2 -type f -printf "%h\0" | uniq -zc | tr '\0' '\n'
```

However, I am getting repeated output. For example,

```
 20 ./WDE/J/P
  2 ./WDE/J/P/Base47
 23 ./WDE/J/P/Base47/b
 12 ./WDE/J/P/Base47
 72 ./WDE/J/P/Base47/c
 46 ./WDE/J/P/Base47
  7 ./WDE/J/P
 23 ./WDE/J/P/z
 23 ./WDE/J/P
```

Directory P has 2 sub-directories and 50 files. They are grouped as 20 7 23 files which does add up to 50. Base47 has 2 directories and 60 files. The counts for b, c and z are correct.  I don't know why the 50 and 60 files have been divided into different lines. There are no hidden files or file names with special characters or spaces.

Comment: Wrong site. You're looking for [ubuntu.se] or [su] instead. This site is for programming related questions, not general computer or OS support. You can find more information about this site in the [help].